# Can't figure out placeholders in perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I am getting a strange error in my code that seems to only happen when I am trying to query with placeholders and quote identifier. I wrote the following subroutine to check if an entry exists and it'll return the key if it exists or `null` if it doesn't:

```
sub check_exists {
    my $table=$_[0];    #table
    my $col=$_[1];
    my $check=$_[2];   #query for item  
    #check if value exists
    my $sql=sprintf(qq(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM %s WHERE ?=?),
                    $dbh->quote_identifier($table));
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($col,$check);     
    my $result=$sth->fetch()->[0];
    $sth->finish();        
    #if value exists find the row and return the primary key
    if ($result){   
        my $sql = sprintf(qq(SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE ?=?),
                    $dbh->quote_identifier=$col,
                    $dbh->quote_identifier=$table);
        my $sth2=$dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth2->execute($col,$check);          
        return ($sth2->fetch()->[0]); #return key
    }
    else {
        return 0;   #else value does not exist and return null
    }    
}
```

I even tried:

```
my $result=$dbh->selectrow_array(sprintf(qq(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM %s WHERE ?=?),$dbh->quote_identifier($table)),undef, $col, $check);
```

Unfortunately, it always always returns zero. If I don't use placeholders it seems to work.

```
my $test=$dbh->selectrow_array(qq(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ORF1 WHERE idORF1=?),undef,$orf1_crc32)
```

Can someone please explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: [You generally can't use placeholders for column names.](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values)

Comment: As noted above, you can't use placeholders for column names, or table names for that matter.  You can only use placeholders for values.

Comment: I thought you can use quote_identifier for tables and columns.

Comment: I see what I did wrong, Embarrassingly, I failed to realize that `WHERE` is looking for a column and I assumed it was a value. It works now once I also used `quote_identifier()` on the column. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from simplifying your code and making it do what the subroutine name *says* it does (i.e., check existence of a record). Your second query does a needless lookup to get a value that is already known to you, **because you passed it to the subroutine** in the first place.

Why not just do a simple `count(*)`, which is optimized in every popular database out there today? A zero/falsy return value means the record doesn't exist, and a non-zero/truthy return value means it does. Simple.

```
sub check_exists {
    my ($table, $col, $val) = @_;

    my $sql = sprintf(
        q{select count(*) from %s where %s = ?},
        $dbh->quote_identifier($table),
        $dbh->quote_identifier($col)
    );

    return $dbh->selectrow_array($sql, undef, $val);
}

if (check_exists('foo', 'bar', 42)) {
    # do something ...
}
```

Comment: You are right, I was just using `count(1)` because I saw that code on a thread relating to finding one instance of an entry. Regarding breaking up the two functions, I need to see if an entry exists and if it does what row is it in. I guess I could just check for the row and if it throws an error then I know it doesn't exist?

Comment: My point wasn't so much about `count(*)` vs. something else, but rather that your logic was strange. Your query boiled down to `select foo from bar where foo=1`---if the record exists, there's a pretty good chance (like 100%) that your return value will be exactly what you passed in. Are you trying to fetch a row's primary key based on some _other_ column?

Comment: Oh thank you. I see what I did, but yes I am trying to return the primary key if the entry does exist. I guess in the second query I am not selecting for the primary key. This would only work if I was only searching the primary key column. Now I see it would be better to split it up into two functions. Sorry I must be too tired.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use placeholders or variables for table or column names.

Instead, use if statements to choose between complete SQL queries.

For example:

```
if($option eq 'name'){
    $sql = 'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ?';
} elsif {$option eq 'id'){
    $sql = 'SELECT age from users WHERE name = ?';
} else {
    // STUFF
}
```

This will generate more lines of code, but your code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied your code correctly.

```
my $sql = sprintf(qq(SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE ?=?),
                    $dbh->quote_identifier=$col,
                    $dbh->quote_identifier=$table);
```

looks funny. I'll bet you meant to say

```
my $sql = sprintf(qq(SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE ?=?),
                    $dbh->quote_identifier($col),
                    $dbh->quote_identifier($table));
```